# Remove \n from multiline quoted string in PyParsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm parsing a multiline quoted string with the following:

The file with the string (test.txt):

```
PROPERTY PName "Multiline quoted 
string" ;
```

The Python code:

```
linebreak = pp.Suppress(';')
identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphanums + '._!<>/[]$')
qs = pp.QuotedString('"', multiline = True)

ifile = open("test.txt",'r')
test_string = ifile.read()
ifile.close()

PROPERTY = (pp.Suppress(pp.Keyword('PROPERTY'))
            + identifier('propName')
            + qs('propValue')
            + linebreak
           )

for t, s, e in PROPERTY.scanString(test_string):
    t.asDict()
```

Which yields:

```
"PROPERTY": {
        "propName": "PName",
        "propValue": "Multiline quoted \n   string"
      }
```

Is it possible to remove the '\n' during the parsing time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really what the `escChar` argument is for, it is to indicate how to escape embedded characters that would normally be quote delimiters.

This is more what I would see as best handled with a parse action, which is a parse-time callback that can modify the tokens right after they are parsed, but before they are returned to the caller.  Here is your code as a console session, adding the parse action `remove_newlines` to `qs`:

```
>>> text = """PROPERTY PName "Multiline quoted 
... string" ;"""
>>> import pyparsing as pp

>>> qs = pp.QuotedString('"', multiline=True)

>>> qs.searchString(text)
([(['Multiline quoted \nstring'], {})], {})

>>> def remove_newlines(t):
...     t[0] = t[0].replace('\n', '')
...     
>>> qs.addParseAction(remove_newlines)

>>> qs.searchString(text)
([(['Multiline quoted string'], {})], {})
```

The `remove_newlines` method is called after a `qs` is successfully parsed, and the resultant tokens are passed to the method as the `t` argument. We can modify these tokens in place. In this method, the newlines are replaced with the empty string, and then assigned back into the tokens, modifying them in place.

Comment: Hello @Paul, I know how to do with this method. I thought there's was some shortcut before using the callbacks. Should I remove my answer since you said `escChar` shouldn't be used in this way? Isn't there some kind of pp.Suppress() to do this? Create a function just to replace a character seems too much.

Comment: You could collapse it down to a lambda with `qs.setParseAction(lambda t: t[0].replace('\n',''))` . But writing a parse action for this kind of manipulation doesn't offend my sensibilities at all.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I found the solution. It may serve as an example as there's none in the user guide.

Just need to insert the `escChar='\n'` in qs:

```
qs = pp.QuotedString('"', multiline = True, escChar='\n')
```

Which Yields:

```
"PROPERTY": {
        "propName": "PName",
        "propValue": "Multiline quoted    string"
      }
```